# SQL WorckBench зависает и не подключается к базе даных

Tags: mysql

**Суть проблемы**: я уже 3 раз переустанавливаю по всем возможным руководствам базу даных MySQL и у меня тупо все зависает на моменте когда необходимо подключится к базе даных. Просто у меня пишет что мы подключаемся долго ждет и нечего не происходит. Если нажмем отмена то высвитит ошибку подключения, очень срочно нужна помощь. Зарание спасибо.

[image: Вот так все зависает и нечего не работает]

[image: А так когда нажимаю "Отмена"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился сам по себе, возможно у кого-то будет таже ошибка как и у меня, поэтому отвечу сам что-бы помочь кому-то, просто вместо того что-бы заходить на созданый по умолчанию конект, нажмите тот серый плюсик и создайте свой, там просто вверху напишите имя введите пароль который вы в момент инсталяции для пользователя root поставили и просто зайдите уже через новый и все отлично работает ).